# no ubuntu gui after removing all python packages

Tags: 18.04, gnome, package-management, xorg, tty

I had some broken packages and as far no other answer helped, I was trying this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189921/695264).

So I ran `sudo apt list | grep python | cut -d "/" -f1 | xargs sudo apt-get remove -y` and after my keyboard didn't work. After restarting I booted into tty (actually tty1 with `started bpfilter` at the top) and there was no GUI. I tried to install x11 via apt (because there where no `startx`) but after `startx` I can only see a black screen with a mouse.

**How can I install all the packages I removed and what should I do?**

my ubuntu version is: 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: And why on earth did you remove all python packages, what were you trying to achieve?

Comment: Fracking bad idea indeed. Doesn’t Debian/ubuntu depend on python for several Scripts? Sounds like “Yeah, let’s remove dash!” Please check if `ubuntu-minimal` has python in its dependencies